# Large samples and normality of residuals

Tags: stata, residuals, normality-assumption

Ok I understand that normality of residuals is not really a concern in large samples. But can anyone tell how large should the sample be to ignore normality. Any cut off point? I'm working with a dataset of 500 observations and my residuals are not normal

Comment: specify what you are trying to do and how strongly your residuals depart from normality. It depends on your question: if you have a highly skewed dataset, it would affect many types of analyses regardless of the sample size (but you are more likely to pick up 'significant' but trite deviation from normality with a larger sample size)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

It depends on *what* you're doing that assumes normality, and it depends on the amount and form of the non-normality. It also depends on what properties you're prepared to tolerate.

In some cases n=5 is plenty, in other cases n=10$^6$ isn't enough.

So ... what are you doing with your data (why do you require normality?), and what are your data like?

Comment: @glen-b: I'm estimating the relationship between poverty and growth with other control variables. Its a project and I need to show all tests of classical linear model are satisfied for my dataset.But I dont get normality, even after removing outliers. Could you please tell me how I can justify my results? Thanks alot

Comment: And its a pooled ols regression

Comment: "*I need to show all tests of classical linear model are satisfied for my dataset*" -- doing formal testing of model assumptions is largely pointless, since doing it answers entirely the wrong question (statistical significance is not really related to impact on inference). This pointlessness applies doubly when it comes to normality, where you're most likely to reject when it matters least of all (in very large samples). Further, if you modify what you do based on the outcome of your test, your subsequent inferential procedures no longer have their nominal properties. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... (Better not to assume things you don't have reason to, if they can badly impact your inference, as a number of papers have recommended.)

Comment: Thankyou. So 500 wont count as a 'very large sample' right?

Comment: It depends! Not *automatically*, but in many (most) everyday real situations it would be more than enough. You just don't give enough detail to be sure.