# OLS and Probit possible on large sample enough?

Tags: least-squares, stata, residuals, normality-assumption, probit

I think I understood that normality of residuals may not be a problem if the sample is large enough (cf, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148367/large-samples-and-normality-of-residuals)).

My question is: Would my sample be large enough to be analysed using a probit and an OLS?

To describe my situation: I am working on a big dataset of some experimental answers. The answers are clearly distributed non normally (bimodal distribution with a majority of 0% and 100%). I want to analyse the dataset using the idea of extensive margin and intensive margin. I have thus two variables: one dichotomous (100% vs not 100%) and one continuous (how much between 0 to 99%). My initial thought would be to use a probit to analyse the first variable (164,000 observations) and an OLS for the second (83,000 observations if I exclude participants declaring 100%).

If there is a need for further information, do not hesitate to ask. Thank you in advance.

Best,
Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stata has a wonderful two-part model command, where the first stage is a logit or probit (extensive margin) and the intensive margin can be any GLM. You could even have different covariates for the two parts. The best intro to this type of model is the Deb, Norton, and Manning book. In your case, you could specify a GLM with a binomial distribution and a logit link function, which is the "fractional logit" of Papke and Wooldridge.  The dependent variable for FL is assumed to a proportion in the (0,1) interval.

The syntax would be something:

```
tpm proportion_var x_var, firstpart(logit) secondpart(glm, family(binomial) link(logit))
```

The references:

Papke, L.E. and J.W. Wooldridge (1996) "Econometric Methods for Fractional Response Variables With an Application to 401 (K) Plan Participation Rates," Journal of Applied Econometrics. Vol 11, No. 6, pp. 619-632.

Deb, P, E.C. Norton, and W.G. Manning. 2017. Health Econometrics Using Stata. Stata Press.

Comment: Thanks for the proposition Dimitriy. However, I do not understand what is wrong with my first message. Why your model would perform better than a simple OLS/probit?

Comment: It would work better because your data does not satisfy the distributional assumptions of OLS. You have a bounded outcome on the intensive margin, which OLS would struggle with. You can use a probit instead of the logit if you like with tpm.

Comment: tpm would also allow you to combine both stages and joint calculate marginal effects.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help. Indeed it sounds very interesting. One last question: why do you specify the family distribution as binomial and the link function as logit for the glm?

Comment: That comes about because the intensive part is a fraction, so you need a fractional logit to handle that.